# Efficient inverse of a square matrix that concatenation of a matrix and a column vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $R$ be a 3x3 rotation matrix and $v=[x,y,c]^T$ be a 3x1 column vector.

Define $Q=[R(:,1:2)|v]$. $(x,y)$ are the only free parameters in my problem and the other elements of $Q$ are fixed. There are a huge number of $(x,y)$ pairs in my problem that I wish to compute $Q^{-1}$ for.

Q1) Is there a nice trick that I can follow in order to reduce the complexity for the whole problem? Like a nicely structured inverse, or some states to compute only once and then keep them using?

Q2) In case there is a nicely structured inverse, does it generalize to higher dimensions? I.e. $Q=[n_1\ n_2 \ n_3 \ ... n_M | v]$ where $\{n_i\}_{i=1:M}$ are orthonormal and $v$ is variable except its last element?